# gridview click event that uses object data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a class (let's call it Object) that contains an ID and some other data. I want to display the IDs in a gridview. When the user clicks on an ID in the gridview table, I want the ability to add code that accesses the object of the ID and display the Object's details (it's ID and other stored data).

So far I've been able to store the data in a tabletable and set it as the gridview source, but I haven't been able to extend the click event feature.

Any ideas on how to implement this in C#?

Comment: what you are looking for is [Master/Details View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335720.aspx) is the same but Ajax enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object used to load into the GridView is gone as soon as the page unloads.  The contents are retained in viewstate, but the object is not there.  What you need to do is query the data again using the selected ID.  Or link the Grid to a DetailsView, which will query the data, as @Wahtever suggested in the comments.